# Access consumer object from ConsumerRebalanceListener using Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

Can you please tell me how to implement ConsumerRebalanceListener. and how I can get the consumer object.

Actually currently I am getting rebalance issue also some the record is missing. I found the solution like we need to use ConsumerRebalanceListener to fix this issue.

I have done this much configuration.

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 100);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 50000);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 40000);
```

Also this much configuration

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new 
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
```

Is this correct to implement ConsumerRebalanceListener or any other solution we have to fix above. 
I am using spring kafka 2.2.2 release and @kafkaListener.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by

> I am getting rebalance issue also some the record is missing.

but spring-kakfa added a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` which extends `ConsumerRebalanceListener` precisely to allow access to the `Consumer`.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the reply. It is working now. But I am facing one issue.                              If any exception getting while sending record to the another server(For ex. Bad Request). Kafka consumer stopped abruptly.

Comment: to elaborate- we process the message from Kafka and downstream api is returning error and exception is thrown. Post that the execution if the normal flow to process the messages is getting stopped. please note that the exception is handled at the application level and logged.
Do we need to use the specific error handling methods provided by the spring kafka library?

Comment: I have created new question. Could you please check and revert. link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957757/kafka-consumer-stopped-abruptly-after-getting-exception