# Kafka consumer stopped abruptly after getting exception

Tags: spring-kafka

Below code snippet :

KafkaConsumerConfig class

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9093");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumerGroupId");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    ConsumerFactory config = consumerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(config);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
    factory.setConcurrency(kafka.getConcurrency());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(0);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new RebalanceListener());
    return factory;
}
```

RebalanceListener class

```
public class RebalanceListener implements ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener {

private Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap;

public void setPartitionToUncommittedOffsetMap(Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap) {
    this.partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap = partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap;
}

private void commitOffsets(Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionToOffsetMap, Consumer consumer) {
    if(partitionToOffsetMap!=null && !partitionToOffsetMap.isEmpty()) {
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> partitionToMetadataMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Map.Entry<TopicPartition, Long> e : partitionToOffsetMap.entrySet()) {
            log.info("Adding partition & offset for topic{}", e.getKey());
            partitionToMetadataMap.put(e.getKey(), new OffsetAndMetadata(e.getValue() + 1));
        }
        log.info("Consumer : {}, committing the offsets : {}", consumer, partitionToMetadataMap);
        consumer.commitSync(partitionToMetadataMap);
        partitionToOffsetMap.clear();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPartitionsRevokedBeforeCommit(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    log.info("Consumer is going to commit the offsets {}",consumer);
    commitOffsets(partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap, consumer);
    log.info("Committed offsets {}",consumer);
}
```

KafkaListner class

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${dimebox.kafka.topicName}'.split('"+ COMMA + "')}", groupId ="${dimebox.kafka.consumerGroupId}")
public void receive(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, final String payload) {
        TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(topic, partition);
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap.put(tp, offset);
    ((RebalanceListener)consumerConfig.kafkaListenerContainerFactory
            (new ApplicationProperties()).getContainerProperties().getConsumerRebalanceListener())
            .setPartitionToUncommittedOffsetMap(partitionToUncommittedOffsetMap);
        LOGGER.info("Insert Message Received from offset : {} ", offset);
        importerService.importer(payload);
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

After this configuration, Kafka consumer stopped abruptly. 
we process the message from Kafka and downstream api is returning error and exception is thrown. Post that the execution if the normal flow to process the messages is getting stopped. please note that the exception is handled at the application level and logged. Do we need to use the specific error handling methods provided by the spring kafka library?

Comment: `Kafka consumer stopped abruptly.` You need to explain what that means. Also, it's not clear why you are committing old offsets when the partitions are revoked - what is that code trying to do - your code will commit offsets as records are processed via the acknowledge; if you want to rewind, you should use seek rather than committing. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to see what is going on.

Comment: @Gary, here "importerService.importer(payload)" we are connecting to different server.  if I will get bad request or any exception from that server then Kafka consumer stopped but If I will restart my server it is start processing.                      As you suggested, Here instead of consumer.commitSync(partitionToMetadataMap we should seek method?

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me to reset the offsets to the beginning positions after you have, presumably, processed some records successfully; you need to explain your use case much more clearly.